# WPF - Import custom fonts in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I would like to import custom fonts on my WPF application so that they work without having the client to install them.

All the answers I have found so far are in XAML, I would like to do it only in C#.

My fonts are in Resources/Fonts/.

I have already tried this :

```
 Fonts.GetFontFamilies(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/#"));
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did everything bluetoothfx said but it still did not work.

Then I changed the Build action of my fonts (it was to Content), to Embedded Resource, and it worked. Resource works also for me.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way that you are working will not work.

**At first create a folder name fonts then Add the font to your project, change its Build Action to Content.**

> > Now you need to find the internal name (Real name) of the font not the font-file name. You can have it by opening the font file and you can see it on top.
> >
> > Now edit **App.xaml**

```
<Application.resources>
<style x:key="MYFONT_INTERNAL_NAME">
    <setter property="TextElement.FontFamily" 
        value="pack://application:,,,/fonts/#MYFONT_INTERNAL_NAME" />
</style>
```

Now use it in your code like:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MYFONT_INTERNAL_NAME}" FontSize="16" Text="Font Style" />
```

To know more search here: 
http://www.alteridem.net/2014/02/24/custom-fonts-in-wpf-applications/

Comment: If I have multiple fonts, can I just add several <style> values ?                                 Furthermore, how can I access this style property from my C# code ?

Comment: Make a settings menu from where you are able to choose font names I mean, you let your user to choose fonts and try to Bind font name Binding{FONT_NAME_PROPERTY} on ViewModel. Then pass the font name. Hope this concept helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765647/using-a-custom-font-in-wpf      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358501/wpf-add-custom-font

Comment: I have put this in my App.xaml:                                `<Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Lato Light">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/fonts/#Lato Light"/>

        </Style>      </Application.Resources>`