# WPF Custom fonts cannot be applied on text

Tags: c#, wpf

I have imported a custom font and set it's Build Action as 'Recourse'. I can see the font listed here [image: here].

When I try to apply it nothing happens. I tried to add it in `<Application.Recourses>`,  in a `<Style>` as well as adding it as a content item or recourse item but nothing happens. Where is the problem and what should I do?

Comment: Do either of these posts answer your question? [Using a custom font in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3765647); [WPF - Add Custom Font](https://stackoverflow.com/q/358501)

Comment: There's a gotcha with custom fonts. Any reference with a relative path means a memory leak. If you do not see c:// in the path then it's relative. Google it. You pretty much need to install or write some code somewhere to load fonts without any leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Build Action to Resource in the properties of the .ttf file
[image]