# How to include fonts as resource?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing an application using WPF, and when I install it on another computer, the fonts that it uses don't exist on the new system, so "Tahoma" by default.

Is there any way that I can compile my application's fonts as resources? If so, how would I need to change the code to use the resource fonts? Would the syntax be something like this?

```
 textblock1.FontFamily = ....."mysegioui.ttf"..;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF - Add Custom Font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358501/wpf-add-custom-font)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303.aspx says this is how you referance it in xaml.

```
<Run FontFamily="/FontLibrary;Component/#Kootenay" FontSize="36">
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
</Run>
```