# wpf / Visual Studio default styles

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012

If I open a new project, and put a label or button on the main window, I get the Segoe UI font at size 12px.

Where is this coming from? Can I choose what I would like the default font / size to be? I had a good look around but can't find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The available fonts are set according to [System.Windows.Media.Fonts.SystemFontFamilies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.media.fonts.systemfontfamilies.aspx).

If multiple versions of the same font family reside in the same directory, the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) font enumeration returns the most recent version of the font. If the version information does not provide resolution, the font with latest timestamp is returned. If the timestamp information is equivalent, the font file that is first in alphabetical order is returned.

There is also [Fonts.SystemTypefaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fonts.systemtypefaces.aspx).

Presumably it is possible to change the selected family or create your own. In fact it is, this post ([WPF - Add Custom Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358501/wpf-add-custom-font)) gives more information on this.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, may look into this but we're probably going away from visual design (Xaml) altogether as it seems so badly structured and difficult to maintain. Doing everything in code behind now.